# How do I know how many times my file has really downloaded?

Tags: php, nginx

The task is to create a controller to count the number of file downloads. It also must be able to account for failed or cancelled downloads. I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to go about accomplishing this.

```
$file = $_GET['download'];
if (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
return filesize($file);`

    $size = filesize($file);
```

Then if the number of bytes given is approximately equal to the file size:

```
    if ( $size < given bytes) {
    $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        $buffer=$buffer+1;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    $fp = fopen("counter.txt", "w"); 
    $test = fwrite( $fp, $buffer); 
    fclose($fp);
}
```

How to know the number of bytes sent by server to the user after clicking on link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with what should be comments:

- You've tagged this as javascript, but your quesiotn appears to have nothing to do with javascript. Please don't do that.
- I assume you are aware of the gaping security hole exposed by your script / that you are not concerned about it.
- Your handling of output buffering is wrong.

> return filesize($file);

- What is this line of code supposed to do?

> header('Expires: 0');

- no.

> header('Pragma: public');

- again, no.

As to your question - its all covered [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php):

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(1);

$file = $_GET['download'];
if (!is_readable($file)) {
   die "No such file";
}
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0; must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

$count=0;
$ih=fopen($file, 'r');
while (CONNECTION_NORMAL==connection_status() && !feof($ih)) {
    print fgets($ih, 4096);
} 
log_completion(feof($ih));
```

BTW: This does not give an accurate record if the file was downloaded - you can only tell if the content has left PHP land.

Comment: ProTip: put code in the lists by indenting with 8 spaces (instead of the usual 4)